# Difficulty writing XPATH to select proper nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am having difficulty getting the xsl:apply-template select to pick up only the desired elements. Each of the following forms for the node element is valid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <node>unimportant</node>
  <node>
    <value>unimportant</value>
    <asdf>important</asdf>
  </node>
  <node>
    <value>unimportant</value>
    <value>unimportant</value>
    <qwerty>important</qwerty>
  </node>
</root>
```

I desire to select just the nodes with 'important' content and avoid the others.  The names of the nodes with important content (asdf & qwerty) are unknown to me and cannot be part of the transform logic.

Here is the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::value)]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>unimportant
  <asdf>important</asdf>
  <qwerty>important</qwerty>
</root>
```

Expected results would be as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <asdf>important</asdf>
  <qwerty>important</qwerty>
</root>
```

The transform is properly selecting the desired elements, but it is also picking up unimportant content from the first node element.  How does one construct a select statement that avoids selecting this content?

Comment: Are the unimportant node names known to you?

Comment: I don't think you've explained the problem well enough. You've given us an example and you've told us how that example should be handled, but you haven't given us the general rules. We don't know which of the strings in your example (value, asdf, qwerty, important, unimportant) are literal strings that appear in your real XML, and which are placeholders for more general content.

Comment: @Michael Kay  Yes, there is a good deal more to this problem than would appear from the example.  I worked hard to distill the problem down to the minimum necessary.Thankfully hr_117 was able to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know which nodes your are not like to treat (`not(self::value)`).
change your

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::value)]"/>
```

to

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::value)]"/>
```

This will ignore the wrong text() nodes

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node[.='important'] | node/*[.='important']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: No, as with the names (asdf, qwerty, etc.), the content of these nodes is arbitrary and not something my group can control.

Comment: So what determines which nodes to copy? Is it any element except `<value>`?

Answer (score -2):

```
//node/*[not(self::value)]
```

Alternately,

```
//node/*[local-name() != "value"]
```

Comment: The self::value form is preferable.